# Minimize nodejs response time with large number of database calls

Tags: node.js, cassandra

One of my api in nodejs does lot of CRUD operations are finally returns, sometimes it takes 10-15 seconds to return. How to offload this task somehow so the response time is quick. And how to handle error occured in offloaded task as response would have gone already?

Currently we are using async module for making parallel calls to cassandra. Some people suggest to use compute-cluster module in nodejs, but to me it would be helpful for computation intensive task. I think my problem heavy on i/o not computation.

Comment: If you don't care about waiting for the operation to complete, you can call res.send() immediately, while still continue processing.

Comment: Does it constantly take that long, or is it intermittent?

Comment: @RomanTumaykin its constant, as its doing 10k updates

Comment: @YuriZarubin i can try that, how to tackle if there is any error on operation post sending response.

Comment: I am trying to exclude a possibility of garbace collection pauses. If this is the case you will see spikes in latency for some inserts around the same time with normal operation after - all under the same load

Comment: @turbo there would be no way of notifying the user that an error happen using during that same request. What you typically do is, you send the response right away, and then you start polling the server to see if the operation is finished. If the user cares enough to stay around for the polling to complete, you can notify the user. This is all assuming you can store the state of the request in some sort of persistent storage. All in all, any solution is going to be a decent amount of work. Your other alternative is to use websockets, but that isn't exactly simple.